# Зацензурить слово в массиве типа char, состоящий из предложений

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, char

мог бы кто-нибудь мне помочь разобраться со второй функцией? 
Я написал одну из них, вот мой код.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char massiv[][100] = {"Hello my name is FUN", "I had a lot of fun", "This function is hard", "This is FUNeral!"};

void printing(char arr[][100], int lines_count){
    for (int i = 0; i < lines_count; i++) {
        cout << massiv[i] << " | ";
    }
    int num;
    num = lines_count;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "There was/were - " << num << " of lines!" << endl;
}



int main(){
    printing(massiv, 2);
}
```

Вот описание функций, и само задание - https://ibb.co/cwFos0 .
У кого плохо с английским скажу русскими словами - в двумерном массиве надо зацензурить слово fun, оно должно быть зацензурено только если написано маленькими буквами - fun, и если является частью слова, например - function станет ***ction.(на скрине есть отличный пример ДО и ПОСЛЕ). У меня не получается написать функцию Change. Я вполне знаю как зацензурить буквы отдельно, но имеено когда они стоят рядом - нет.

Comment: Текст задания следует приводить прямо в вопросе. И какая проблема возникла с приведенным кодом - тоже.

Comment: *"У кого плохо с английским скажу русскими словами"* Тут дело не в том, что у нас плохо с английским (хотя то, что задание перевели - это хорошо; сайт ведь русскоязычный), а в том, что ссылка может испортиться. SO рассчитан на то, чтобы накапливать полезные вопросы и ответы, а с битыми ссылками от них толку мало.

Comment: Попробуйте искать нужное слово в строке через `std::strstr` или что-то подобное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ищем все вхождения подстроки `fun` в строках и заменяем их на звездочки.

```
void change(char arr[][100], int lines_count)
{
    char* next = nullptr;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines_count; ++i)
    {
        next = arr[i];
        while (next = std::strstr(next, "fun"))
        {
            next[0] = next[1] = next[2] = '*';
        }
    }
}
```

[std::strstr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strstr), [online test](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4DOiMiekx9xbs5Hr)

Comment: Я понимаю, что слово `fun` короткое, но все равно жаба душит... Почему бы не добавлять внутри `while (...)  {` к `next` троечку?

Comment: @avp, по-хорошему в эту функцию вобще должно приходить нецензурное слово, в `while(...)` еще цикл который заменит все `strlen` нецензурных букв и затем увеличить `next` уже на `strlen`. А это так - топором по дереву

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @acade за идею кода. Вот мой код который я написал, может кому тоже будет нужен.

```
void changing(char arr[][100], int lines_count){
    for (int i = 0; i < lines_count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            if (arr[i][j] == 'f' && arr[i][j+1] == 'u' && arr[i][j+2] == 'n') {
                arr[i][j] = '*';
                arr[i][j+1] = '*';
                arr[i][j+2] = '*';
            }
            cout << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
```